# Constants in matrix integration

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Suppose you have an integral of a matrix-valued function of the form:$$\int_a^b B A(t) C dt$$

In this case, the notation $A(t)$ is to denote a matrix that depends on the integrated variable $t$ (for example $A(t) = e^{tA}$), where the matrices $B$ and $C$ are independent of $t$. Is the following necessarily true as it would be for the analogous scalar problem?

$$\int_a^b BA(t)Cdt = B\int_a^bA(t)Cdt = \int_a^b BA(t)d t C = B\int_a^b A(t)dt C$$

Comment: The answer is affirmative and it is easy to prove for the particular case of  $A$ being square. Recall the expansion $e^{tA}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} (t^k / k!) A^k=I+tA+(t^2/2!) A^2+...$ where it the identity matrix has the same dimensions as $A$. Therefore  the integral of $A(t)$, say $H_A$, won't change dimensions and your operation $B\: H_A \: C$ is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is.. Let $A(t) = (a_{ij})(t)_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$, $B = (b_{ij})_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$ and $BA(t) = (\beta_{ij}(t))_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$. We only want to prove it for $BA(t)$. The other case is an analogue. Then, for each $i, j$ we have:
$$
\left(\int_a^b BA(t)~\mathrm{d}t\right)_{ij} =\int_a^b \beta_{ij}(t)~\mathrm{d}t = \int_a ^b \sum_{j = 1}^n b_{ij}a_{ij}(t) ~\mathrm{d}t = \sum_{j = 1}^n \int_a ^b b_{ij} a_{ij}(t)~\mathrm{d}t = \sum_{j = 1}^n b_{ij} \int_a^b a_{ij}(t)~\mathrm{d}t = \left( B\int^b_a A(t)~\mathrm{d}t \right)_{ij}
$$

Comment: I see. Is it not necessarily true if the matrices are different sizes? In this case I have, for example, $A$ is $n\times n$ and $B$ is $m\times n$ with $m<n$

Comment: Oh yes, if I look at it twice it also holds for any dimension. Just substitute $m = n$ if necessary. It has to be true, I remember using this in an ODE class.